# Change Page Title After a Certain Time

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically change the title of a page after 2 seconds (2000 ms).

Here is the code I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Before</title>
</head>
<body onload="updateTitle">
<script>
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title');
function updateTitle() {
//Here is some kind of delay (of 2 seconds). I have tried setTimeout(), setInterval() and delay()
title.innerHTML = "After";
</script>
Dummy Content for Body
</body>
</html>
```

How might this be modified so that after 2 seconds, the page title changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For changing the title, you should rather be using `window.title`

```
window.title = 'After';
```

In case, you absolutely must use `document.getElementsByTagName`, note that it returns an *array* of elements, the first of which you need to make use of. i.e.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'After';
```

Of course, if the page does not have a `<title>` element, the above will result in an error. The first one (`window.alert`) will work in either case.

---

**Delay**

For introducing the delay, you can use `setTimeout` (as you've already done)

```
<script>
function updateTitle() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.title = 'After';
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

---

**Full page working code**:

Notice that the  block containing `updateTitle()` has been moved to the . The issue was that the function `updateTitle()` was not yet defined when the browser tried to bind it to `onload` (while parsing the page) - as it was defined afterwards inside the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Before</title>
<script>
function updateTitle() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'After';
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="updateTitle()">
Dummy Content for Body
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to not work.
<br /><br />
`<body onload="updateTitle">`<br />
`<script>`<br />
`setTimeout(function updateTitle() {`<br />
`    window.title = 'After';`<br />
`}, 2000);`<br />
`</script>`

Comment: The `<body>` tag should be `<body onload="updateTitle()">`. Notice the `()` after `updateTitle`

Comment: Oops.  I forgot about that.

Comment: "[12:35:29.564] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol." and "[12:35:29.582] ReferenceError: updateTitle is not defined"

Comment: Move the `<script>` block to the `<head>`. The issue is that the function `updateTitle()` is not yet defined when the browser tries to *bind* it (while parsing the page) - as it is defined after wards inside the body.